# Change converted format into ISO date - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data where a date is stored as text, for example:

> Jan 01, 2001

I see a number of examples showing how to format a datetime to this format but I'm looking for a function to change it back to a date.

What is even more confusing is what I tried gives me "2020-01-01."  Any suggestions?

```
DECLARE @d varchar(10) = 'Jan 01, 2001'
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(date, @d)
```

[image: sql result]

I'm using SQL Server 2014.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your string is not long enough.  Declare it with a long-enough length:

```
DECLARE @d varchar(255) = 'Jan 01, 2001';

SELECT TRY_CONVERT(date, @d);
```

If you show the value of `@d`, you will see what this code returns:

```
DECLARE @d varchar(10) = 'Jan 01, 2001';

SELECT @d, TRY_CONVERT(date, @d);
```

which is `'Jan 01, 20'`.  SQL Server interprets that as 2020.

Comment: speechless.  should i delete the question?